# laravel migration command in cmd is not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-jetstream

I have installed laravel jetstream(livewire) and was trying to migrate. but it's showing the following message :

```
F:\laravel\testauth>php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table

Illuminate\Database\QueryException

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 
767 bytes (SQL: alter table `val` add unique `val_email_unique`(`email`))
```

and in server http://127.0.0.1:8000

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'testauth.sessions' doesn't exist (SQL: 
select * from `sessions` where `id` = s2DP9nN1I65FxTeqR6vrUwiZ4XQj25kGa5JTCjEE limit 1)
```

Comment: ok, I got it. Thanks for your kind help :)